# Check against server time to display SQL entries - Radio Station DJ Rotator Plugin

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wordpress

I'm building a WordPress plugin that will create a radio station "On-Air Now" DJ rotator. I need help with the logic.

**Working options panel I've built so far:**[image: screen shot of my plugin]

I've based the idea on a PHP case statement I wrote back in 2007 where you specify the DJ's start time which is then checked against the server time. (See the code: https://github.com/gregrickaby/Jock-Rotator/blob/master/mod_jock.php)

I just don't know how to code the logic behind showing only ONE DJ during his/her scheduled TIME-FRAME.* e.g.; 6a-9a.

**Would it be?**

script: *"hello server, what time is it?"*

server: *"it's 6:25am"*

script: *"ok, database it's 6:25am...who is scheduled?"*

database: *"neal boortz"*

script: *"thank you sir. i will now write some HTML"*

**What I have built so far:** 
https://github.com/gregrickaby/DJ-Rotator-for-WordPress/blob/master/dj-rotator-for-wordpress.php

### EDIT: SOLVED

Thanks to @Scott for the suggestion. It was exactly what I needed to see.

if **$day** equals today, and **$start_time** is less than or equal to **$now** AND **$end_time** is greater than or equal to **$now**, then write some content.

The code below works. Thank you!

```
$day = date('w');
$now = date('Hi'); 
 foreach((array)$jrwp_images as $image => $data) {
  if($data['days'] == $day && $data['start_time'] <= $now && $data['end_time'] >= $now)
   echo '<!-- the content here -->' 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just run an SQL query that basically says:

```
SELECT * FROM deejays WHERE start_time >= $now AND end_time <= $now
```

Assuming `$now = time()`

It'd mean converting the start and end times to timestamps before inserting them into the DB, but you can look into `strtotime()` for that, it's quite a simple process (You may have to change the required format from 600/900 etc to 06:00.